# error: initialization with "{...}" expected for aggregate object - c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
struct test
{
    unsigned int test1;
    unsigned char test2[4096];
    unsigned int test3;
} foo

struct foobar
{
unsigned char data[4096];
}
```

if i want to access the struct, i say foo.test1, foo.test2[4096], etc..
however, when I wish to return the data present in foo.test2 in the following manner

```
pac.datafoo = foo.test2[4096];

unsigned char data[4096] =  pac.datafoo;
```

this is the error I get:

```
error: initialization with "{...}" expected for aggregate object
```

what is the mistake i'm doing?

Comment: Is there any other information i'm missign to provide?

Comment: Yes: what's `pac`, what's `datafoo`, ...

Comment: Pac is also a struct. datafoo is a unsigned char.

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate the code that defines / declares them

Comment: added. is there anything else that you might need.

Comment: You don't have a `datafoo` member in your `test` class...

Comment: If datafoo is an unsigned character then you can't assign an unsigned character to an array.  The compiler is expecting you to assign an array and the error message means that it was expecting an initializer surrounded by { and }

Comment: btw, `foo.test2[4096]` is out of boundry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to learn the array initialization method. It's NOT simply assigned as the single variable.

Some examples:

```
int arrayone[3] = {0}; // assign all items with 0

int arraytwo[3] = {1, 2, 3 }; // assign each item with 1, 2 and 3

int arraythree[3]; // assign arraythree with arraytwo
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    arraythree[i] = arraytwo[i];
}
```

Comment: Note about `int arrayone[3] = {0};` it only assigns all elements `0` because that's the default value, which is how the last two elements are constructed. In the same sense `int a[3] = {};` assigns them all to `0`; however, the important distinction here is that `int a[3] = {2};` does *not* assign them all `2` - the first element is assigned `2` and the others are default constructed into `0`

Answer (score 4):

add ";" at the end of the struct.

```
struct test
{
    unsigned int test1;
    unsigned char test2[4096];
    unsigned int test3;
} foo ;

struct foobar
{
unsigned char data[4096];
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char * data;

  data = pac.datafoo;
```