# Build error E0530 initialization with '{..}' expected for aggregate object

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, initialization

I am trying to create an array with size 'i' here, where i is defined previously,(full code at bottom)

```
double studentScores[] = new double[i];
```

However I keep getting the following error:

> initialization with '{...}' expected.

I have tried  the pointer method however that does not seem to work with the rest of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inData;                //input file stream variable
    ofstream outData;           //output file stream variable

    inData.open("Data.txt");        //open data file
    outData.open("testStatistics.out");

    int i = 0;
    while (inData.eof() == false)   //while you have not reached the end of the file
    {
        i++;                            //i == size of the class
    }
    double studentScores[] = new double[i];     //creates an array of the size of the number of inputs

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        inData >> studentScores[j]; //read in student scores
    }

    double average1 = average(i, studentScores);
    double median1 = median(i, studentScores);

    int distribution[10] = { 0 };
    for (int v = 0; v < i; v++)         //increment distribution appropriately
    {
        int h = scoresDistribution(v, studentScores);
        distribution[h] ++;
    }

    outData << "There are " << i << "scores available." << endl;
    outData << "The average is : " << average1 << endl;
    outData << "The median is : " << median1 << endl;
    outData << "The detailed grade distribution is as follows : " << endl;

    outData << fixed << left;
    outData << setfill(' ') << setw(10) << "range" << setw(10) << " # of Students" << endl;
    int z = 100;
    int y = 90;
    for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++)
    {
        outData << setfill(' ');
        outData << setw(10) << "[" << z << " - " << y << "]";
        outData << distribution[f] << endl;
        z = z - 10;
        y = y - 10;
    }

    inData.close(); //close input data file
    outData.close(); //close output data file

    cout << "Press any key to quit…" << endl;

    cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: initialization with "{...}" expected for aggregate object - c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924399/error-initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
double studentScores[] = new double[i];
```

This is not valid `C++`. This looks like a cruel `C++`/`Java` hybrid.

You can't create an array on the stack here, because doing so requires a fixed size known at compile time.

The best way in modern `C++` is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> studentScores;
studentScores.resize(i);
```

If you must use `new`, you must use a pointer, because that's what `new` returns:

```
double* studentScores = new double[i];
```

Please note that you **must** free that memory yourself when you're done using it:

```
delete[] studentScores;
```

In either case, if *"that does not seem to work with the rest of my code"*, you need to fix the rest of your code. You might want to ask a separate question for that or use search to find a question that can help you.