# How to rename a file with a "unknown" name in C++?

Tags: c++, rename, fstream

A VM creates a file and a .vbs gets it's directory and name. Simply by checking for .m4a files in a directory. (there is only one at a time) and I'd like to rename the file, It says there is no such file or directory though.

```
   ifstream infile;
   infile.open("A:\\Spotify\\Sidifyindex\\indexchecker.txt");
```

The file says "Z:\Spotify\Sidify test out\01 VVS.m4a"

```
   getline(infile, VMin);
   infile >> VMin;
   infile.close();
   //clear drive letter
   VMin.erase(0, 1);
   //add new drive letter
   VMin = "A" + VMin;
   //copy file dir
   string outpath;
   outpath = VMin;

   //get new file name
   outpath.erase(0, 30);
   outpath = "A:\\Spotify\\Sidify test out\\" + outpath;
   //convert to const char*
   const char * c = VMin.c_str();
   const char * d = outpath.c_str();

   //rename
   int result;
   char oldname[] = "VMin.c_str()";
   char newname[] = "outpath.c_str()";
   result = rename(oldname, newname);
   if (result == 0)
     puts("File successfully renamed");
    else
        perror("Error renaming file");

    cout << VMin << endl;
    cout << outpath << endl;
```

I'm getting "Error remaining file: no such file or directory"
Output is correct "A:\Spotify\Sidify test out\01 VVS.m4a" and
"A:\Spotify\Sidify test out\VVS.m4a"

I assume that the issue is hidden somewhere in the rename part

Comment: `outpath.erase(0, 30);` surely the clear function is a better choice here. What if the existing name was more than 30 characters long? Not that it matters since you assign over anything that was there the next line.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's impossible the path is always be 30 characters long. The .vbs file indexing this directory indexes only this directory so all files there start with "Z:\Spotify\Sidify test out\" which is converted in C++ to "A:\Spotify\Sidify test out\" and the first 3 chars are deleted as well, so that only "VVS.m4a" remains. Oh well the number might be larger than 100 actually. hmm. but only in theory this won't happen here realistically. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
char oldname[] = "VMin.c_str()";
char newname[] = "outpath.c_str()";
```

but you probably meant to do:

```
char oldname* = VMin.c_str();
char newname* = outpath.c_str();
```

The first variant will look for a file which is called "VMin.c_str()" which does not exist and thus you are getting this error. You accidentally have put C++ code into quotes. Quotes are only for verbatim strings, like messages and fixed filenames. But your filenames are determined programmatically.

You can use the `const char *` `c` and `d` you are calculating above and pass these to `rename()`.

Comment: wait, let me try

Comment: Getting 4 errors with that 2x E0520 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924399/error-initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object-c and 2x C2440 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?view=vs-2017

Comment: oldname and newname need to be `char*` and not `char[]`, but you should do what the last line of this answer says and just use `c` and `d`