# Can I use conditional operator to initialize C style string literal?

Tags: c++, initialization, conditional-operator

I'm trying to use the ternary operator (`?:`) to initialize a character array to either one string or another

```cpp
char answ[] = ans > 0 ? "Anton" : "Danik";
```

Where `ans` is just an integer obtained earlier and I keep getting the error:

```
initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object
```

Is it that you simply can't initialize arrays through a ternary operator?

---

I also tried this:

```cpp
char answ[] = { ans>0 ? "Anton" : "Danik" };
```

What gave the error:

```
value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924399/error-initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: initialization with "{...}" expected for aggregate object - c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924399/error-initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it that you simply can't initialize arrays through a ternary operator?

Indeed, you can't.

In your example, you don't want to have just array. You want to have string literal - a specific array. Unfortunately, compiler doesn't treat `answ` as one, because of you try to use conditional operator for initialization. Compiler treats it directly as array of `char`s.

But there is different method of declaring C strings - using `const` and pointer.

```c
const char* answ = ans > 0 ? "Anton" : "Danik";
```

The downside of this approach is, well, `const` - you cannot modify this string.

That's why, if you are using C++, you should use its strings - `std::string` :

```cpp
std::string answ = ans > 0 ? "Anton" : "Danik";
```

---

In C, you could do:

```c
char answ[6];
ans > 0 ? strcpy(answ, "Anton") : strcpy(answ, "Danik");
```

But at this point, ternary operator is just less verbose than normal *if-else*, so don't do that.